# Is there a way to set APIM Policy to send Azure Function API key in request header using 'x-functions-key' instead of sending it from query parameter?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

Is there a way to set API management Policy to send Azure Function API key in request header using 'x-functions-key' instead of sending it from query parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During Function App import APIM backend entity is created: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/backend/createorupdate
This entity includes a reference to a key stored in properties. You can use rest API to fetch your current and move key from query to header.

Answer (score 0):

The `set-header` policy can be used to set the value of http headers. More information -> [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader)

Example :

```
<set-header name="some header name" exists-action="override">
    <value>20</value>
</set-header>
```

Comment: API key needs to be removed from query parameter after its added as header.  API key is internally added as query parameter by APIM in <backend>section and the request is forwarded.
<backend> allows only one policy and it has to be <forward-request />, hence i am not able to remove Api key from query parameter